# Why font-size in iPhone mail so tiny? Had to scale up to 26px

Tags: ios, email, responsive-design, newsletter

I'm working on a responsive email template for my employer. For the desktop size, I was able to leave the default font size at 16px and just use rem to adjust sizes as necessary. It looks fine on the desktop, in Gmail, and is fully responsive. However, when viewed in Mail on iPhone, the font is SO SMALL. I had to add a media query that increases the base font size to 26px to get reasonable font sizes in the email. I've tried doing some research, but it doesn't seem as if other people have had to do the same. There is very little CSS in the code, but here is what I have:

```
body, table, td, a, p, span {-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;} 

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    html, td {
        font-size: 26px !important;
        line-height: 1.3;
    }
}
```

I also have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

There is some other CSS having to do with resizing images, with margins, etc. but that is the only CSS dealing with font-sizes (all the rem info is inline so it isn't stripped out by Bronto/Gmail). If I resize it in the browser to a mobile size, the text looks massive, but when viewed on my iPhone, it looks great. I'm concerned that this may be an iPhone quirk though and that it will look massive on other types of devices. Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, finally figured it out. Luckily I had been going through and making all our email templates responsive, and one of them didn't have a hero image. Guess what? The font size looked massive on mobile for the imageless-template! So after some experimentation, I found that

```
img {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

completely resolved the issue, so that now the actual font-size matches what is set in the CSS. Despite all the width:100% styles set on the image itself and on its parent containers, somehow the image must have been too large and triggered a resize of all content, I guess? If anyone has an explanation I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code from the templates I use (where I don't see this issue):

Try making your `<meta>` tags look more like this:

```
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

The first tag disables auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail, which could be affecting your text size. The second tag sets the viewport; forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary and could be throwing off your design.

---

Also try moving the inline body styles from the `<body>` tag to inside a universal selector in `<style>`, like so:

```
<style>
    /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
    * {
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
</style>

<body width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got the same result after trying that.

Comment: Hmm, how are you setting font size? Your post mentions `rem`... have you tried using `px`? Old school, I know, but email clients...

Comment: I'm using rem. I really don't want to switch to px, especially since then I can't increase the size for mobile, which I would want to likely anyway even if it were working as expected (e.g. have the base size be 18px for mobile vs 16px for desktop).

Comment: **You can increase `font-size` on mobile using only `px`** by overriding one `px` value with another in a `media query`. Though if you want stick with `rem` I won't talk you out of it.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but I think I'm going to stick with rem. The way that Bronto strips classes off elements, it would actually be really tough to set the font sizes in the CSS anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of the viewport meta tag? You should consider adding this tag to the meta on your site. Just be cautious though as it could manipulate other HTML elements you have already configured.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Here is a link to a page explaining what it does in further detail.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Thank you, I should have mentioned that I do have that already. I will add that to my description.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the page on multiple browsers? Are they all giving the same results?

Comment: Do you mean multiple browsers on my phone? (since my phone is where I am getting the unusual result). I've tried in Safari on my phone- I actually don't have any other browsers on there. I will see what is available in the app store.

Comment: Okay, I tested it on my iPhone in both Chrome and Firefox and the font size looks fine. It actually looks like the head is getting stripped out in Gmail in those browsers (my link color change is being ignored), so the media query font size change may not even be coming into play.

Comment: If you are using a style sheet and not in-lining html, some email clients like Gmail will strip out the style sheet. Check out how the email looks in Chrome and use the inspector to simulate an iPhone to see what the size looks like. This will allow you to click on an example of the text size and see if there is a class influencing size in mobile.

Comment: Or I should have said part of or all of a style sheet. Gmail used to ignore them entirely. Now they function to a degree.

Comment: Using the device simulator in Chrome, the font size looks overly large, as would be expected for a font size of 26px. Mail on the iPhone is definitely not ignoring the stylesheet however, as the font-size is much smaller when I don't specify the font-size at all, or if I set it as something smaller, like 20px. Chrome and Firefox on the iPhone may be ignoring it however as they are clearly ignoring the style changing the link colors (which works fine in the Mail app). I have noticed that Gmail strips out the embedded stylesheet on a desktop as well (it strips out the head apparently).

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I think you are complicating your life trying to use the `text-size-adjust` property.

According to the browser compatibility chart on [this MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust?v=control), there is poor browser support and it's buggy.

Secondly, the way I read  [this W3C doc](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-size-adjust/#text-size-adjust) I don't think you are using it for its intended purpose. W3C states that:

> This module contains features of CSS relating to one possible
> mechanism for adapting pages designed for desktop computer displays
> for display on smaller screens such as those of mobile phones...

Its purpose is to provide a solution for pages which were designed for desktop display only.

As you know, older web pages which don't use the viewport meta tag will be scaled down to fit the viewport of a mobile device. The problem with this is that text often becomes too small to read and this `text-size-adjust` property proposes to remedy this by enlarging text on mobile devices.

I think if you continue to use the viewport meta tag, make your template responsive, and size elements so that they display well in all devices you would get good results if you don't use `text-size-adjust`, i.e. some like the following:

```css
body, table, td, a, p, span {font-size:16px;}
```

Good sources of info about `text-size-adjust`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust?v=control
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-size-adjust/#text-size-adjust
https://caniuse.com/#search=font-size-adjust

Comment: Thanks, but I tried taking out that line of CSS but ended up with the same result.

Comment: Thx @bansheekitty, you might want to double check if you have other elements in your template which aren't responsive, eg images, tables or other elements with hard coded dimensions

Comment: The template uses a series of tables because it is an email template and unfortunately that's how you have to code those, but everything is responsive (I've tested it). Nothing has a hard-coded dimension (the only non-percentage width is just setting a max-width on the container). I'm starting to think it's just a weird mobile thing. It looks fine in Mail on iPhone, in the mail app on Android, and in Chrome and Firefox on iPhone.